# Use Java to check if user has entered something in two EditText boxes in an Android application

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext, boolean-expression

I am developing a simple Android application that currently works when the user enters a number (the EditText box won't allow other characters to be inputted from the XML code), presses a button and the number is processed with several mathematical steps to give an output in a result TextView on the same screen. So far so good - the App works!  However, to avoid making two Android applications and keeping it all on one screen/application, I wish to add a similar second user EditText input so that a slightly different answer is given (a slight alteration of the maths there and the user knows about this), so the user can choose which input box to add the numerals to. If I duplicate much of the code (with different object:id names etc.) an error obviously occurs. Probably I need to use a conditional statement of the if....else or conditional OR variety to return a boolean true/false and process accordingly.  If no input was received in one input box, the Java code then checks (and) processes the input in the other EditText box or whatever input widget could be used. I am happy to use two input choices and a button for each and two answer TextView widgets (if it is easier to code this) or just keep only one button and one answer TextView output. Is there standardised code for this, considering only one (JavaMainActivity) Java file is used and necessary Android activity XML files to incorporate these additions?

In order to use the two RadioButtons (as suggested) on the screen, the Java code is presented below for checking. The XML code for the additional widgets is okay in the other XML file. The compiler flags four errors due to unresolved symbols.

The following method is called when the button is clicked on the screen. This is only part of the MainActivity Java file to demonstrate the main functional code to be edited/changed. I have remembered to add the android.widget.RadioButton package.

```
    public void add(View v)
    {

    //initialize objects
    TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    EditText edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    // get text from edit text boxes and convert into double
    double a=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(edit1.getText()));

    //do the maths (as an example)

    double b = a + 1000;
    double c = b/5;


    // display maths output on TextView - I left this comment as this is where the
    // result.setText(.....) is normally placed without the radio button choices.


    // Alternative maths for second choice of result for the App user.
    double a1=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(edit1.getText()));

    double b1 = a1 * 1000;
    double c1 = b1 * 5;


    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.small:
    if (checked)
    result.setText("Answer:"+c);

    break;
    case R.id.large:
    if (checked)
    result.setText("Answer:"+c1);
    break;
    }
 }
```

// compiler cannot resolve symbol 'result' and 'c', 'c1'. Errors.

You might like to check where the data is coming from in the display/activity XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter a number"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff">
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small answer"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large answer"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#F9FF19" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click for answer"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:textColor="#f9ff19" />
```

Comment: You might want to use the **same** EditText. Just add a CheckBox to set the "variant". Or you can use 2 RadioButtons to make the choice even clearer. Depending on the user choice, you'll process the input in `a slightly different` way

Comment: Thanks for that, I like the idea of using two RadioButtons to give the user their choice for desired output (criteria).  Is there a website/code for this activity?

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you declare your variables outside the function declaration since it seems that `onRadioButtonClicked` uses variables declared in add method. In general, due to scope issues, `onRadioButtonClicked` cannot access `c1`, and `c2` declared inside add.

A better way is to declare variables as member variables of the `MainActivity` class (usually I would set them private and use getter/setter methods to access them):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView result;
    EditText edit1;
    double c;
    double c1;
    //your code
}
```

Then you have to be aware that if variables result, `c`, and `c1` are not defined before you click on your radio buttons (which triggers the `onRadioButtonClicked` method), you will run into error because you are performing operations on undefined variables such as `result.setText`. Hence, you must consider the order in which the functions are fired. I would suggest that you trigger add function after the user chooses the radio button. For example:

```
public void add(){
    //code check for which radioButton is selected, or no radioButton is selected your code
    //code to calculate according to whichever radioButton is selected your code
    //display your code
}
```

This way, selecting a radio button without `c`, `c1`, or `result` defined won't cause the app to shut down.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Declaring the variables as class variables as you suggest works better overall. I can get the code to compile but the application shuts down when the user clicks on the desired RadioButton on the device. Errors are reported when I try to nest? the onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {....} method within the add(){...} method. Perhaps I need to experiment around with the code more!